# printf() function in C

Tags: c, printf

I can't believe I'm stuck here but I can't seem to get over this.
I want to put a `long` integer in the middle of a sentence.

I get this output;

```
Howdy, I am 166662
Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.019 s
Press any key to continue
```

I am using codeblocks to run this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  long mn = 166662;
  printf("Howdy, I am %ld",mn,"i hope that you had a better better day than I  having.\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read the printf spec: First format string, then parameters.

Comment: `"Howdy, I am %ld"` --> `"Howdy, I am %ld. %s"`

Comment: [Read the documentation on `printf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf). It doesn't work this way.

Comment: Pretty sure I saw doubles many times and recently... but cannot find them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the printf spec: First format string, then parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    long mn = 166662;
    printf("Howdy, I am %ld i hope that you had a better better day than I am having.\n", mn );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, i totally forgot... :/ Thank you for your help.

Comment: @chummed, I can only assume you also totally forgot how to read `man` pages, or how to do a little research before polluting SO with, ... dubious content :-) Please make sure you read the guidelines at some point, they'll make your time here as painless as possible in future.